# Will my program require increasing amounts of memory if I don't pair my MPI_Isend's with MPI_Wait?

Tags: fortran, mpi

I parallelized a Fortran code using MPI.  At the share points, I send all the data out to the buffer using MPI_Isend from all processes in the model.  Then, each process goes and collects the data it needs using MPI_Recv.  Since MPI_Recv is blocking, I know that each process is getting the data it needs before moving on with its calculations.  Therefore, I just ignored the request code that MPI_Isend gives to me.  I set it to some integer that I do not retain.  I never call MPI_Wait.  When I run my code, I notice that it is gobbling up more memory at every iteration and I'm wondering if it's because I'm not calling MPI_Wait since, in the documentation, MPI_Wait says:

> If the communication object associated with this request was created
>   by a nonblocking send or receive call, then the object is **deallocated**
>   by the call to MPI_WAIT and the request handle is set to
>   MPI_REQUEST_NULL.

Do you think this is why my program is eating more memory throughout the run?

Comment: Yes.  http://www.slideshare.net/jsquyres/friends-dont-let-friends-leak-mpirequests .

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I need to come up with a system for storing/retrieving the request codes now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `MPI_Request` associated with MPI communication functions such as your `MPI_ISend` will be allocated memory, and must be cleaned up throough MPI (as opposed to `delete`).

The memory will not be given back until one of 3 things happens:

- A wait such as `MPI_Wait` completes on the request, freeing it.
- An `MPI_Test` returns success, also freeing it.
- The request is freed using `MPI_Request_free`.

It is possible to free an active request (i.e. an `MPI_Request` for a message that is not finished transmission), which will continue to send but the `MPI_Request` will no longer be valid for any uses such as testing, waiting etc.

Comment: Yes, I changed my data-sharing system to store the request codes and make the necessary calls to MPI_Wait to free up the memory.  My code is now chugging along using a constant amount of memory throughout the entire simulation rather than eating every bit of RAM on the cluster.